# Conditional Matching in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets.  Each has a column A that has an account number.  But each has a different info about that account.  The accounts also don't share the same set there maybe some the other doesn't have.  What I want to do is check Sheet one column A vs sheet two column A and based on that populate a cell in Sheet 1 with Sheet two column B.  Could anybody help me with how I might do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "conditional" matching? From the body of your question I see just a regular matching case. Have you tried `MATCH()` or `VLOOKUP()` ? From what I understand these 2 functions might solve your problem.

Comment: I understand that those are the functions I need.  I am having some issues with the formatting.  I am a programmer and our statistician is currently sick, spreadsheets are not something I ever do.  I completely understand the logic I just keep getting href# errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Sheet2 looks like this:
[image]

You can use `VLOOKUP` in Sheet1. This formula would work: `=vlookup(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`
You can see it put in the cell C2:
[image]

If you don't like the `#N/A` error you can embrace the formula in `IFERROR` with the parameter `""` which would yield an empty string:
`=iferror(vlookup(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"")`